# UITableViewController scroll default behaviour

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiscrollview, uitextview

I'm using a UITableviewController with textField and text view in cells. By default when i click on a textfield the tableviewcontroller scroll the content up for let me se the content of the field. This default behaviour is very useful, but i've implemented a toolbar with a done button (inputAccessoryView) when i edit the textView. This is a problem when I switch from editing the textField to editing the textView, because the toolbar of the keyboard is just above the textView.

I've tryed a lot of solutions but nothing work for me. I've tryed something like this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

but doesn't work for me because i suppose this behaviour is already implemented in UITableViewController.

PS: the UITableViewController was created with Interface Builder. I don't know if this information is useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set up your UITableViewController to implement the UITextViewDelegate protocol, then you can know when you begin editing the textView by implementing this method:

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{ 
     //then you can scroll the tableview up so you can see the textView 
     [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, /*height of your toolbar*/) animated:YES];
}
```